# How to use Google Publisher Tags Ads correctly in Nuxt Composition Api projects?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, google-publisher-tag

I use Compositon Api and ı implemented GPT ad service. It works well when I first time loaded page but if i switch between pages , my ad area disappears and and I get error messages.

**ads.js**

```
export const adIntegration = () => {
  const adScript = document.createElement('script');
  adScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  adScript.src = 'https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js';
  document.head.appendChild(adScript);
 
};
  
export const mainPageAd = ({ path, size, id }) => {
 
  adIntegration();

  window.googletag = window.googletag || { cmd: [] };

  googletag.cmd.push(() => {
    googletag.defineSlot(path, size, id).addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display(id);
  }); 

};
```

**index.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
.home-page 
    .advertisement( :id="adSlot.id" style='min-width: 955px; min-height: 240px')
     
<script>
import { mainPageAd } from '~/common/utils/ads';

setup(){ 

 const adSlots = ref({
      path: '/21737763597/adunit-1',
      size: [320, 100],
      id: 'div-gpt-ad-1559997122392-0',
    });

 onMounted(() => {
  mainPageAd({ path: adSlot.value.path, size: adSlot.value.size, id: adSlot.value.id });
    
}

return{adSlots}
```

**My errors**

**first :** Error in googletag.defineSlot: Cannot create slot /1347001/main-masthead. Div element "div-gpt-ad-1559997122392-0" is already associated with another slot: /1347001/main-masthead.

**second :** pubads_impl_2022092701.js?cb=31069995:18 Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addService')

Comment: Isn't this kind of thing supposed to be injected globally? Why would you be putting it on every page on mounted? Inject it once in the main layout so that it will available everywhere.

Comment: i need to show different ads for every page even if they have same layout. Because we show our own ads not from google . For example sport page should show ads about sport , magazine should show about magazines. one layout can have many many child pages

Comment: You need to unmount them somehow (their your service's API on how to proceed) otherwise you will get those kind of issues + your app will be super slow pretty quickly.

Comment: i was calling    window.googletag?.cmd?.push(() => {
    window.googletag.destroySlots();
  }) when onUnmounted page . but it was not working so i use  delete window.googletag; now and it works well . but ı dunno if it is a good solution

Comment: May not cause the bug anymore but it's not removing the loaded code neither so kinda a workaround. Don't have anything in their official API?

Comment: you should try refreshing the ad slots instead of destroying the instance.

Comment: if (window.googletag) window.googletag.pubads().refresh();    i tried refreshing and now it works well

Answer (score 1):

```js
export const adIntegration = () => {
  const adScript = document.createElement('script');

  adScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  adScript.src = 'https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js';
  document.head.appendChild(adScript);
};

export const mainPageAd = ({ path, size, id }) => {
  adIntegration();

  if (window.googletag) window.googletag.pubads().refresh();

  window.googletag = window.googletag || { cmd: [] };

  googletag.cmd.push(() => {
    googletag.defineSlot(path, size, id).addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display(id);
  });
};
```